# remove subview of uiwindow?

Tags: ios, ios5, window, calayer, subview

i want to remove a view from uiwindow,so i nslog in appdelegate method,it says window's subviews count as two `NSLog(@"   %d",[[self.window subviews] count]);` so how can i remove that subviews from window,if i remove that subviews i have tab bar controller to be continued...

```
- (void) GetUserCompleted

{
    NSLog(@"   %@",[[self.window subviews] objectAtIndex:0]);   
    NSLog(@"   %@",[[self.window subviews] objectAtIndex:1]); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by ",if i remove that subviews i have tab bar controller to be continued..."?

Comment: @trojanfoe i temporarliy call one viewcontroller and then i want to remove that view...if i remove that view,i have tab bar controller behind...

Comment: You'll want to have one content view showing at all times, so that sounds right to me?  If you are using a tab bar controller then you will display whatever view is selected by the tab bar controller, so why would you remove any view at all?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can remove the a single subview using the following code.

```
[subview_Name removeFromSuperview];
```

if you want to remove all subviews form the view then use this.

```
NSArray *subViewArray = [self.window subviews];
for (id obj in subViewArray)
{
    [obj removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: thank u vinu!!!!i got some idea!!!but it removes all object!!!i want to remove a particular uiview?how can i?

Comment: And what happens to the view controllers associated with these views?  This might remove the view, but I think the OP is misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 11):

Swift version of @Maddy 's answer:

```
//create view then add a tag to it. The tag references the view
var myNewView = UIView()
myNewView.tag = 100

//add the  view you just created to the window
window.addSubview(myNewView)

//remove the view you just created from the window. Use the same tag reference
window.viewWithTag(100)?.removeFromSuperview
```

**Update**

Here is another way to remove a UIView without using a tag from the window. The key is the view has to be an instance property.

```
lazy var myNewView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    return view
}()

viewDidLoad() {

    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow) else { return }

    window.addsubView(myNewView)
}

// call this in deinit or wherever you want to remove myNewView
func removeViewFromWindow() {

    guard let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: \.isKeyWindow) else { return }

    if myNewView.isDescendant(of: window) {
        print("myNewView isDescendant of window")
    }

    for view in window.subviews as [UIView] where view == myNewView {
        view.removeFromSuperview()
        break
    }

    if myNewView.isDescendant(of: window) {
        print("myNewView isDescendant of window")
    } else {
        print("myNewView is REMOVED from window") // THIS WILL PRINT
    }
}

deinit() {
    removeViewFromWindow()
}
```

Comment: Really interesting, this solution works for me, but I still don't understand why  just calling myNewView. removeFromSuperview() doesn't work? Any ideas?

Comment: I’m not sure either. I’ll look into when I get some time and get back to you. You can always post it as a new question too!

Comment: It's possible that when you call `removeFromSuperview` on a specific variable, there's a another copy of it on the window. So it's removing the view that you're asking it to, but leaving the other copy that looks the same, and that's why it looks like it's doing nothing.

Comment: @l.vasilev hi, I just found a new way to remove a view from the UIWindow by using `.removeFromSuperview()`.  I updated my answer with it.

Answer (score 10):

Hope the below code will be useful for remove particular view

```
   Set tag for that remove view

   subview.tag = 1;

   then

   [[[self window] viewWithTag:1] removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: No known class method for selector 'window'

Comment: @ShahbazAkram you can [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow in Objective C. For swift you can use UIApplication.shared.keyWindow

[keywindow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622924-keywindow) 
`This property holds the UIWindow object in the windows array that is most recently sent the makeKeyAndVisible() message.`

Comment: Thanks. Much better than iterating all subviews. Just make sure to choose safe tag. so tag collision has the smallest probability. I chose -15 for example :)