# How should I make Floating Button only exist specific ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift

In my App, there's a lot of ViewController

I have created floating button in one of theme.

But Is it possible add it to another ViewControllers that I need?

Not whole App, only specific ViewController

Creating Floating Button I referenced

[Swift: Floating Plus button over Tableview using The StoryBoard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725528/swift-floating-plus-button-over-tableview-using-the-storyboard)

Comment: Just don't subclass the `FloatingButtonViewController` then it won't show?

Comment: Give your button a unique tag, like `button.tag = 123321`. and create a method like removeFloatingButton() in which you can remove this button,  `[[[self window] viewWithTag: 123321] removeFromSuperview];`. Call this method when you don't need button. You can refer this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14997175/5350718

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For Particular View Controller** :

Hey You just need to drag button on tableview using xib or storyboard for specific view controller nothing else i have attached below screenshot[image]:

**For Through out the App** :

Or if you want to add floating button through out the app then use this link to implement floating button :

[In iOS, how do I create a button that is always on top of all other view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777558/in-ios-how-do-i-create-a-button-that-is-always-on-top-of-all-other-view-control)